# Wordpress user page via plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

How would one go about adding a custom page to a wordpress installation via a plugin.  For instance the plugin adds a new page_template, the user creates a blank page using that template and the plugin populates the information there?

Answer (score 0):

I find [Extended User Profile](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/extended-user-profile/) rather good, although it doesn't quite work in the way you've described but the end result seems to be what you want.